# How to find the lowest place value in a number

Tags: python

I am writing a program that takes percent errors into consideration and one thing I would like to be able to do is find the lowest-place value in a number.

Example:

```
1000 has the lowest place of 1    
12.0 has the lowest place of 0.1    
3.1415 has the lowest place of 0.0001    
etc...
```

Is there a **built-in function** I could use or is there a simple operation I could write?

Comment: `3.1415` is a very peculiar case of _integer_ =)

Comment: I don't know of a builtin function but it is an easy operation on strings. If value (as str) doesn't contain a `.`, answer is 1. Otherwise detect length (number of digits) after comma and put together `.`, one `0` less than detected length and a `1`.

Comment: You're going to have serious problems with floating-point rounding error, but also with just the plain existence of real numbers with no terminating decimal expansion. You're not going to get anything sensible out of trying to find the "lowest place value" of `1/3`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thankfully, for my purposes, all of my numbers are rational terminating decimals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No builtin function

But this function is able to find the value you are looking for.

```py
def e_reformat(s_number: str) -> str:
    try:
        e_index = s_number.index("e")
    except ValueError:
        return s_number
    e_number = int(s_number[e_index + 1 :])
    prefix_number = s_number[:e_index].replace(".", "")
    return f'0.{"0"*(-e_number-1)}{prefix_number}'

def lowest_place(number: float | str) -> str:
    s_number = e_reformat(str(number).lower())
    try:
        dot_index = s_number.index(".")
    except ValueError:
        return "1"
    after_dot = s_number[dot_index + 1 :]
    return f"0.{'0' * (len(after_dot) - 1)}1"
```

Tests:

```py
>>> lowest_place(1000)
'1'
>>> lowest_place(12.0)
'0.1'
>>> lowest_place(3.1415)
'0.0001'
>>> lowest_place('1.00')
'0.01'
>>> 1.2e-9 == 0.0000000012, lowest_place(1.2e-9) == lowest_place('0.0000000012')
(True, True)
```

---

### ⚠️`lowest_place(1.)` or `lowest_place('1.')` returns `'0.1'`. If you expect the value to be `'1'`, use this `lowest_place` function instead:

```py
def lowest_place(number: float | str) -> str:
    s_number = e_reformat(str(number).lower())
    try:
        dot_index = s_number.index(".")
    except ValueError:
        return "1"
    after_dot = s_number[dot_index + 1 :]

    if not after_dot:
        return "1"

    return f"0.{'0' * (len(after_dot) - 1)}1"
```

Comment: Edited: if you need `lowest_place(1.00)` and `lowest_place(1.2e-9)` to works, you can sent those as strings i.e `lowest_place('0.0000000012') > 0.0000000001`

Comment: I added `e_reformat()` to handle floats like `1.2e-9`. `lowest_place(1.2e-9) == lowest_place('0.0000000012')`returns `True`